# drawing on top of a listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to make a listview appear to fade to black towards the top of it. Essentially I want to turn something like this:

[image: original list]

in to something like this:

[image: desired effect]

I tried two different approaches to this:
The first one was to override the onDraw() of the ListView, this did not work, my "extra" drawing happened behind the listView. The second approach was to put another view on top of the listView, this looks right, but if the user tries to scroll the list by touching the screen where the view is it does not scroll, it seems like the view consumes the touchevent, so about a third of the list is untouchable.

Any tips on how I can implement this?

Comment: You can implement View.onTouchListener at overlying View and return false (event hasn't been consumed by listener) in onTouch method.

Comment: so if I return false in the listener the event will go on to the next view underneath it?

Comment: Yes http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

Comment: But with this approach it would be difficult to find the item clicked.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign the listitem background in a customised view. In getview (of adapter class) based on the item position. Create a gradient in xml and increase the alpha value based on the position.

This is the peice of code which is working for me.

listItem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="64dp">    
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

ItemAdapter.java

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(rowResourceId, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    int id = Integer.parseInt(Ids[position]);
    textView.setText(Model.GetbyId(id).name);

   // this is the main idea behind the UX look n feel.
    rowView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
    textView.setAlpha((float) position/Ids.length);

    return rowView;

}
```

Please feel free to use holder design pattern in the getView. This is just a proof of concept.